# Uniform continuity on an open interval with one end point as infinity

Tags: real-analysis

I have read a statement: if $f$ is continuous on $(a, \infty)$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ exist and $\lim_{x \to a^+}f(x)$ exist and are finite, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a, \infty)$.Is this statement correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know / have you proven that a continuous function on a closed and bounded interval $[b, c]$ is uniformly continuous?

Comment: But I have asked about the open interval where one end point is infinity

Comment: I know. However, if you know about the closed and bounded interval, then that makes the proof of your case easier.

Comment: Ok.got it.Thanku